# Код Хэмминга и преобразование слова в двоичный код

Tags: c#

Код Хэмминга в C# с использованием ранее программы для преобразования слова в двоичный код.

Не могу разобраться, как применить код Хэмминга в C#. Вычитал много способов. В том числе про формулу

```
P1=D1^D2^D3^D4^D5^D6^D7^D8
```

Как сложение по модулю два заменить в этой формуле? И правильно ли я использую формулу?
Как соединить с уже написанной программой?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[]args) {

            Console.WriteLine("Введите слова с латинскими буквами =");
            string S = Console.ReadLine();
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                switch (S[i]) {
                case 'А':
                    c = 192;
                    break;
                    case 'Б':c = 193;
                    break;
                    case 'В':c = 194;
                    break;
                    case 'Г':c = 195;
                    break;
                    case 'Д':c = 196;
                    break;
                    case 'Е':c = 197;
                    break;
                    case 'Ж':c = 198;
                    break;
                    case 'З':c = 199;
                    break;
                    case 'И':c = 200;
                    break;
                    case 'Й':c = 201;
                    break;
                    case 'К':c = 202;
                    break;
                    case 'Л':c = 203;
                    break;
                    case 'М':c = 204;
                    break;
                    case 'Н':c = 205;
                    break;
                    case 'О':c = 206;
                    break;
                    case 'П':c = 207;
                    break;
                    case 'Р':c = 208;
                    break;
                    case 'С':c = 209;
                    break;
                    case 'Т':c = 210;
                    break;
                    case 'У':c = 211;
                    break;
                    case 'Ф':c = 212;
                    break;
                    case 'Х':c = 213;
                    break;
                    case 'Ц':c = 214;
                    break;
                    case 'Ч':c = 215;
                    break;
                    case 'Ш':c = 216;
                    break;
                    case 'Щ':c = 217;
                    break;
                    case 'Ъ':c = 218;
                    break;
                    case 'Ы':c = 219;
                    break;
                    case 'Ь':c = 220;
                    break;
                    case 'Э':c = 221;
                    break;
                    case 'Ю':c = 222;
                    break;
                    case 'Я':c = 223;
                    break;
                    case 'а':c = 224;
                    break;
                    case 'б':c = 225;
                    break;
                    case 'в':c = 226;
                    break;
                    case 'г':c = 227;
                    break;
                    case 'д':c = 228;
                    break;
                    case 'е':c = 229;
                    break;
                    case 'ж':c = 230;
                    break;
                    case 'з':c = 231;
                    break;
                    case 'и':c = 232;
                    break;
                    case 'й':c = 233;
                    break;
                    case 'к':c = 234;
                    break;
                    case 'л':c = 235;
                    break;
                    case 'м':c = 236;
                    break;
                    case 'н':c = 237;
                    break;
                    case 'о':c = 238;
                    break;
                    case 'п':c = 239;
                    break;
                    case 'р':c = 240;
                    break;
                    case 'с':c = 241;
                    break;
                    case 'т':c = 242;
                    break;
                    case 'у':c = 243;
                    break;
                    case 'ф':c = 244;
                    break;
                    case 'х':c = 245;
                    break;
                    case 'ц':c = 246;
                    break;
                    case 'ч':c = 247;
                    break;
                    case 'ш':c = 248;
                    break;
                    case 'щ':c = 249;
                    break;
                    case 'ъ':c = 250;
                    break;
                    case 'ы':c = 251;
                    break;
                    case 'ь':c = 252;
                    break;
                    case 'э':c = 253;
                    break;
                    case 'ю':c = 254;
                    break;
                    case 'я':c = 255;
                    break;
                }
                // Исходное число. float num = c;    
                var intList = new List < int >();
                float frac = c;

                var t = Console.ReadLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < t.Length; j++)
                     Console.Write(Convert.ToString(t[j], 2));

                // Преобразуем в двоичное представление.
                var iFrac = (int) frac;
                while (iFrac > 0) {
                    intList.Add(iFrac % 2);
                    iFrac = iFrac / 2;
                } 
                intList.Reverse();

                // Выводим результат.
                foreach(int j in intList)
                    Console.Write(j);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        private static float FractionalPart(float d) {
            return d - (float) Math.Truncate(d);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: О___о Господи, что это?

Comment: Творение неопытного новичка. )))

Comment: Но работает, как нужно по заданию. )

Comment: вас самих такой огромный switch не пугает? почему не делать просто

    с = (int)S[i];//'А' => 1040, Ъ => 1066, Ы => 1067

и ещё очень интересно смотрится фраза в начале:

>Введите слова с латинскими буквами

когда дальше только работа с кирилицей

Comment: Как хорошо, что у Вас не с китайским языком программа должна работать.

Comment: а что даст это выражение?с = (int)S[i];

Comment: он больше ошибок вызвол чем помог

Comment: попрошу больше не путать или помочь по вопросам!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю то, что вы хотели достичь вашим кодом, то проще посмотреть готовые исходники и разобраться в них.

- [Код Хэмминга. Пример работы алгоритма](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140611/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)
- [Hamming code algorithm C#](http://maciejlis.com/hamming-code-algorithm-c-sharp/)

P.S. Исходную строку можно перевести в массив байтов так:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
```

Comment: не-не-не, тогда уж лучше `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);`